# Use input element as content in tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Let's assume I have a bootstrap tooltip appended on a div element

```
<div class="text-center text" data-container="body" 
     data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" 
     data-content="Some content">Text</div>
```

How can I create an input element to use as a content, instead of just text.

I've tried

```
data-content="<input type='text'>
```

But it returnts it as a string.
Also creating an input object and trying to append it with javascript doesn't work:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type="text";
myTooltip.setAttribute("data-content", input);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try to set `content` as callback function, which returns valid html

Comment: would if make any difference? The setAttribute - way gives me [object HTMLInputElement] as content in the tooltip, which is a valid HTML element. The data-container is assigned without problem.(because in my implementation I overwrite some classes from the bootstrat to make a custom one). I just can't assign a right content.

Comment: you should differentiate between a tooltip and a popover! similar structure but different and if you have  data-toggle="popover" in your html and $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip(); in your js - it will nae work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set `data-html` attribute to `true` to use `html` content or title for popover.

see [jsfidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/1g8a57e2/1/)

*ps: it has no sense for `hover` trigger.*

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin: 250px;"
       data-placement="left"
       data-trigger="click"
       data-html="true">test</a>



$(".btn").popover({ content : '<b>test</b><input type="text">' });
```